# Should default "get" accessor descriptor (with defined "set" accessor descriptor) have type "undefined"?

Tags: typescript

If we look at this example:

```
class MyClass {                                                              

  private _myVar: string;                                                    

  public constructor() {                                                     
    this._myVar = 'Hello world!';                                            
  }                                                                          

  public set myVar(value: string) {                                          
    this._myVar = value;                                                     
  }                                                                          

}                                                                            

const myObj = new MyClass();                                                 

const otherVar: string = myObj.myVar;
```

There is no error produced, but should there be?

The class doesn't have a `get` key for the `myVar` property, so it defaults to `undefined`, yet the TypeScript compiler doesn't pick up on that and says the last `otherVar` assignment is fine.

Shouldn't that last assignment error out?

Comment: When you create a `property`, all keys are reserved. `get` is defined, but returns `undefined`. In my opinion an error should be thrown when compiling to indicate the missing getter. You may inform an issue to their github page.

Comment: I shall open an issue on the tracker, but if look at the JS that gets compiled from that TS, there is no `get` defined (just the `set`).

Comment: I should rephrase what I said before. All keys of a property descriptor are reserved. AFAIK get method is defined in the property descriptor, but will return undefined, same as `writable` defaults to false for properties defining a value. The above is a legal statement to call the property of `myVar`, thus no error is thrown. However, this should be detectable when compiling and would be better to have the compiler throw an error instead. `get` and `set` in instances of classes are essentially defined the same as the descriptor parameter in `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue had already been raised here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11596